# Redirect to a specific page but need to use variables

Tags: php, html, sql, database, web

I'm not sure if there may be already an answer to my question because I don't really know how to call this problem...

I created a Database and connected it to my website by using php - everything successfull so far. The Database contains different Playlistnames. Now. If you search for a Playlist on the page and it shows you the results (Playlistnames) they are underlined. What I want is to redirect them to a specific page where all the containing songs of the playlist are listed.

Here is the code:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){


echo "<div>";
echo "<ul>"; 
echo "<li>"."Playlist:"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp". "<a href=\"OurPlaylists.php?id=\">".     
    $Playlist =$row['Playlist'].
    "</a>";
echo "</li>";
echo "<li>"."Song(s):"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp".     
   $Song=$row['Song'];

echo "</li>";
    echo "<li>"."Genre:"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp"."&nbsp".      
    $Genre =$row['Genre'].
     "</li>";
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";

}
}

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$contactid=$_GET['id'];//Buchstabenreiheeinstellungen

}

?>
```

I know the code looks awkward but I'm just an average pupil trying to get my project done. 
I believe there are tuts and whatever out there but what I've found in my google safari so far wasn't fitting for me (I either understood the english or it was something different).

So I'd appreciate it if you could take 1 or 2 minutes for my problem.
Thank you so much <3 (Sorry for the probably worst english ever)...

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions.  They are deprecated. If you are just learning, learn to use mysqli or PDO.  As far as your question goes, It seems you have created a link to the playlist page, but you are not showing any code of the playlist page in question. You just need to build the logic on that page to take the passed `id` parameter and display the appropriate records from the database.  You are not showing any of this code here in your question, so there is really nothing to give help on.

Comment: That's exactly my problem though. I don't know what I'm supposed to code on the page you get redirected to when clicking the link is it $_POST is it $_GET or do I want to solve this by the completly wrong way?!

Comment: Based on the link you have built, you would get the playlist id at `$_GET['id']`. Of course, you actually need to insert the id into the link that you are building, which you currently are not doing.  Also, there is no redirection here that I can see, so not clear on why you mention redirection.  You are just linking directly to the playlist script page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the header method to redirect the user to a new page. The URL must be absolute and this must be called before you output anything.

```
header("Location: http://example.com/other-page.php?contactid=$contactid");
```

As others pointed out you should not use `mysql_*` functions and should use `PDO` or `mysqli` once you learn about objects in PHP. In the meantime you should at least use `mysqli_*` functions instead of `mysql_*`.